# Change RegEx Validation on textbox based on dropdown selection

Tags: jquery-validate

I have a working example of replacing Validation methods based on a dropdown's selection.

The issue I'm having is using a regex with the JQueryValidation, entering a valid Twitter address always returns the Invalid Address error.

The below function runs when the Page loads, I set the Default Validation, then I add new validation when the dropdown is changed.

jsFiddle - [here](https://jsfiddle.net/timcadieux/xqp64fo5/31/)

```
ValidationDefaults();

//Setup all .Select2
$(".select2").select2({
  theme: 'bootstrap4',
  placeholder: '- Search -',
});

$('#SocialMediaNetworkId').on('select2:select', function(e) {
  var data = e.params.data;
  AccountNameLabel(data.id);
});

$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function(e) {

  if ($("form").valid()) {
    /* $('#Edit').submit();*/
  }
});

function AccountNameLabel(SocialMediaNetworkId) {
  $("#Edit").data('validator').resetForm();
  switch (parseInt(SocialMediaNetworkId)) {
    case 1:
      $("label[for='SocialMediaAccountName']").text("FaceBook Url");
      $("#SocialMediaAccountName").attr("placeholder", "FaceBook Url - Ex. https://www.FaceBook.com/joeblow");
      FaceBookValidation();
      break;
    case 2:
      $("label[for='SocialMediaAccountName']").text("YouTube Url");
      $("#SocialMediaAccountName").attr("placeholder", "YouTube Url - Ex. https://www.YouTube.com/joeblow");
      YouTubeValidation();
      break;
    case 3:
      $("label[for='SocialMediaAccountName']").html("Twitter Url");
      $("#SocialMediaAccountName").attr("placeholder", "Twitter Url - Ex. https://www.twitter.com/joeblow");
      TwitterValidation();
      break;
    case 4:
      $("label[for='SocialMediaAccountName']").text("Instagram Url");
      $("#SocialMediaAccountName").attr("placeholder", "Instagram Url - Ex. https://www.Instagram.com/joeblow");
      InstagramValidation();
      break;
  }
}

function ValidationDefaults() {

  $('#Edit').validate({
    rules: {
      SocialMediaNetworkId: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      SocialMediaNetworkId: "* Required Field"
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      error.addClass('invalid-feedback');
      element.closest('.form-group').append(error);
    },
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
    }
  });

}

function TwitterValidation() {

var settings = $('#Edit').validate().settings;

$("#SocialMediaAccountName").rules("remove");
$("#SocialMediaAccountName").rules("add",
    {
        required: true,
        pattern: "/http(?:s)?:\/\/(?:www\.)?twitter\.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/",
        messages: {
            required: "Required input",
            pattern: "* Must be a valid Twitter URL - Ex. https://www.twitter.com/joeblow"
        }
    }
);
//$("#SocialMediaAccountName").rules("add", {
//    required: true,
//    pattern: {
//        required: "/http(?:s)?:\/\/(?:www\.)?twitter\.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/"
//    },
//    messages: {
//        required: "Required input",
//        pattern: "* Must be a valid Twitter URL - Ex. https://www.twitter.com/joeblow"
//    }
//});

//// Modify validation settings
//$.extend(true, settings, {
//    rules: {
//        // Add validation
//        "SocialMediaAccountName": {
//            required: true,
//            pattern: "/http(?:s)?:\/\/(?:www\.)?twitter\.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/"
//        }
//    }
//});
//$.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
//    required: "* Required Field.",
//    pattern: "* Must be a valid Twitter URL - Ex. https://www.twitter.com/joeblow"
//});

}
```

Comment: You can only dynamically modify or change rules on a field through the `.rules()` method.  Please refer to the docs.

Comment: I have updated my code and the fiddle to reflect the suggestion but I am getting th same result where the url is listed as incorrect.  I'm not certain if its a Validate issue or the regex is incorrect.

Comment: Why are you adding and removing the `required` rule each time?  You can set the `required` rule once and just add/remove each `pattern`.

Comment: Looking at your fiddle, based on the changing validation message, it seems to be working and that you have a problem with your regex.

Comment: Yes, check your regex.  Remove the double quotes... your fiddle is working for me but you wrote it case sensitive.

Comment: OMG, that's all it was, the quotes